# Swig and %rename filters

Tags: swig

Is there a way to run multiple filters in a single %rename call in SWIG?

I know from the manual that I can use a line like this:

```
%rename("%(strip:[H3D])s") "";
```

which will turn all methods such as "H3DFoo" in to "Foo".  There are other in-built filters for doing case transformation, but there is no documentation on how to do multiple steps.

Using another %rename replaces the filter, and I haven't found a separator to run multiple filters on the string.  So, it appears possible to convert type casing *or* remove a prefix and not both.

In this particular case it *might* be possible to use the regex filter, but it would be nice to be able to both remove a prefix *and* convert type casing.  The other option is to put a %rename on every single declaration, but this defeats the purpose of %rename being able to apply to a module in general.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I'd be inclined to go for the variant of `%rename` that can call a command if your rules are more complicated than a single variant or a regex.

I would use perl personally and it has a plethora of CPAN modules for [things like renaming](http://search.cpan.org/~hio/String-CamelCase-0.02/lib/String/CamelCase.pm), e.g.:

```
%rename("command:perl build/rename.pl <<<")
```

The manual [warns against this](http://www.swig.org/Doc2.0/SWIG.html#SWIG_advanced_renaming) because it's slow spawning processes to perform it. Given that typically you don't run SWIG very often I don't see that as a huge draw back.

Comment: This is actually what I did in the project I was testing with, though using Ruby instead of Perl.  Saying that its slow is an understatement; it MAJORLY wrecks the performance.  Maybe this isn't as bad with faster-to-start scripts, but my simple test showed that a near-instantaneous swig file with 10 definitions went from near-instant to taking ~3 seconds.

Comment: @Skrylar I sympathise, waiting 3 seconds for your build must really suck.